# The connection to "domain" is not secure in Chrome

Tags: .htaccess, google-chrome, ssl

Over the past few months, I've been frequently encountering [the message](https://app.screencast.com/IWaytpOWMJvSV) "The connection to example.com is not secure." This issue generally arises when I'm accessing webpages that use **http** instead of https. It doesn't occur every time, but it's fairly consistent. Surprisingly, I'm facing this problem even with [my own](http://ssfurnishings.com/) websites where I have SSL implemented and have https redirect. However, I continue to see [this error](https://www.screencast.com/t/agXa7xDXfe6d) quite often, something that didn't happen until the past few months.

Here's the rewrite rule I've used:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Your rewrite seems fine, is there anything else in your .htaccess file? Also, this is a Wordpress site correct? What is your permalink settings for the site?

Comment: @Joe Yes its a multisite setup, apart from this W3TC code and blocking few files.
For permalink: /blog/%postname%/%post_id%/